# Does JFreeChart support this type of bar chart?

Tags: java, jfreechart

I need to render a chart like this:

[image]

**NOTE: I don't need the average lines**, just the basic layout.
I need to specify a few key groups ("Bill Clinton", "Ronald Reagan" etc. in this example) and then assign any number of sub-keys to each group (years in the example provided). Can it be done in JFreeChart? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do the subgrouping on the axis without writing a custom subclass of `CategoryAxis`.  Everything else can be handled with the existing API.

Answer (score 1):

As per the [examples](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/samples.html) on the site, I'd say yes.  By combining a labelled line chart (as with Line Chart Demo 5 on their online demo) and a bar (any bar chart demo) chart plot into a dual axis plot (dual axis demo 1 below).

In fact, Overlaid Bar Chart Demo 1 and Overlaid Bar Chart Demo 2 combined are pretty much exactly what you want.

http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/samples.html

[image]

Comment: They are not exactly the same. In this chart, each category has the same set of sub-keys (S1, S2 and S3), however in my example each president has his own unique set of sub-keys (which are years in office). I can roughly re-create that in JFreeChart by simply assigning each category only those sub-keys I need, this however creates a really ugly plot because JFreeChart thinks that all categories should have the same set of sub-keys, so with the example chart it would assign Reagan all the years from 1988 to 2003 and plot 0 for those years he was no longer in office. Thanks anyway,it was helpful

Comment: You are talking about the additional X axis? Can't you just add a custom X axis, I assume it support multiple.

Answer (score 1):

If you go to this link:

[JFreeChart showcase jar](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/jfreechart-1.0.13-demo.jnlp)

you can download a jar file which will launch via JNLP (Java network launcher protocol)   This will showcase a large range of charts that can be created with JFree, including bar charts.  I believe it contains proof that charts similar to what you desire can be made.

NOTE: You may need to tweak your security settings to run the jar file

[image: JFree chart showcase]

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I think it should work see [this](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/images/GroupedStackedBarRendererSample.png://) image is created with JFreeChart